# I want to build a backend service like Kinvey using Node.js, Sails.js and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, mongodb

Hi I want to build a backend service like Kinvey(for HTML and HTML5) using node.js, sails.js and mongodb. Where I can create, post, update, and delete like it happens in [Kinvey](http://www.kinvey.com).
Example code for HTML:

```
    var promise = Kinvey.DataStore.save('collection-name', {
    _id  : 'optional-id',
    prop : 'value'
});
promise.then(function(entity) {
    ...
}, function(error) {
    ...
});
```

Link: http://devcenter.kinvey.com/html5-v1/guides/datastore#Saving

I am new to MEAN stack and sails.js. Please suggest if there are any better framework or approach to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you are trying to use sail.js then internally it contains the orm layer called waterline.

Waterline provides the same instance method like kinvey say

1. find
2. update
3. destroy
4. save
5. create

and all these methods are promise based.
There are so many adapter available in the open-source world and by using them we can easily change our database layer without changing any code.

so in sails you can easily use

```
//I think this is same as kinvey

Model.save()
.then(function(response){
    //code here related to success code
 }).catch(function(error){
     //error code
 })
```

For full documentation you can refer to

https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs